# Sense organ suppression as a sadhna

Tags: scripture, yoga, tantra, guru, sadhana

[Podcast with Sarvesh Shashi](https://youtu.be/x0NTMSFBmv0)

5:28-6:00

He mentions

> Not touching ,
> Staying silent,
> Vipasana,etc.

Can someone elaborate on what sadhanas is Sarvesh referencing to?
Please also give scripture reference.

Thank you.

Comment: Vipassana is Buddhism concept not related to Sanātana.

Comment: Oh,I don’t know why Sarvesh mentioned it,then.Thank you for the information.!

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - but the topics are common - moun vrat, upavaas, brahmacharya etc. are all penances in any religion.